# Selenium Json and xml read from Url that get method open it with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to know can get json data or xml data from selenium ChromeDrive?

```
{
    "name": "Rajeev",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "Karnataka",
        "country": "India"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy 
do this

```
webDriver.getPageSource()
```

getPageSource() methods for get all contents in web view you can see just remove on necessary tags with regex

[Introduction to driver.getPageSource()](http://www.abodeqa.com/introduction-to-driver-getpagesource/)

Comment: thanks a lot , but I need better way without regex , I tested and worked .